# Disable Submit Button

Tags: jquery

i have several array checkbox, 1 submit button and 1 dropdown menu
how can i disable/enable this submit button and dropdown menu when 1 or many checkbox is checked.
when this submit button is disable and user click on it, dialog box appear tell no checkbox is checked

something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/frantic912/3YbZu/

```
setButton(buttonGroup) {
    var retArr = new Array();
    if (buttonGroup[0]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < buttonGroup.length; i++) {
            if (buttonGroup[i].checked) {
                document.frm_search.send.disabled = true;
                alert('Please check the first checkbox!');
            }
        }
    }
}


<form  method="post" name="frm_search">
    <table>
        <tr>  
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="appr[]" id="appr" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" onclick="setButton(this);"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bla bla bla</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="slct_appr" id="slct_appr" >
                    <option value="1">-- Please Choose --</option>
            <option value="2">Approve</option>
                    <option value="3">None</option>
                </select>
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input name="submit" class="submit" id="send" type="submit"  value="send" />
              <input name="txt_action" type="hidden" id="txt_action" value="frm_add_submit" />
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: alot but still not working

function setButton(buttonGroup) {
   var retArr = new Array();

   if (buttonGroup[0]) {
      for (var i=0; i<buttonGroup.length; i++) {
         if (buttonGroup[i].checked) {
document.frm_search.send.disabled=true;
alert('Please check the first checkbox!');
         }
      }
   }
}

Comment: There is an expectation on SO that you post what you have tried, even if it hasn't worked. This prevents questions that boil down to 'do this for me.' So if you could please post a little jQuery to show what you tried it would be great. Even better you could post a http://www.jsfiddle.net (no account required)

Comment: For future reference you can edit your original question. I have added the js from your comment into the body of your question for you. Thank you for taking the time to post the js.

Comment: ok tq..i try upload at jsfiddle.net

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you requirement is like this. Please check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3YbZu/5/)** and let me know if its fine to you.

**DESCRIPTION**

```
 $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function(){
    var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
    if(n > 0){
        $("#send, #slct_lulus").attr("disabled",false)
        return true;
        $("#frm_submit").submit();
    }
    else{
        alert('Please Tick a checkbox!');
        //prevent form submission
        $("#send, #slct_lulus").attr("disabled",true)

    }
});
```

In above code on every click I am checking the length of check box if its greater than 0 then we are allowing to submit the from else we are not allowing to submit the from and making same time disabled of submit button.

There is few changes in HTML markup as well like this

```
<td><select name="slct_lulus" id="slct_lulus" disabled=true>
                <option value="1">-- Please Choose --</option>
                <option value="2">Approve</option>
                <option value="3">None</option>
                </select></td>
    <td><input name="submit" id="send" type="submit" disabled=true  value="Send" /></td>
```

On page load I disabled the select box and button to initial page submit.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward with jQuery. I put comments throughout the code which are self-explanatory.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljef5/

```
//monitor inputs of type checkbox for a change
$('input[type=checkbox]').change( function() {
    //how many checkboxes are now checked?
    var numChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (numChecked == 0) { 
        //disable the send button
        $('#send').prop('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    }
    else {
        //enable the send button
        $('#send').prop('disabled', ''); 
    }
});

//watch for when the form is submitted
$('form').submit(function() {
    var numChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (numChecked == 0) {
        //warn user that no checkboxes are checked
        alert('Tick a checkbox!');
        //prevent form submission
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to load jQuery. There is a dropdown on the left handside of jsfiddle where you pick which library to load. I just cut and pasted my code into that fiddle. One last, small, thing. Add `disabled="disabled"` to the submit button so that it is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to enable/disable button and dropdown menu.

checkbox checked event.

```
<script> 
function apply(buttonGroup) 
{
    var retArr = new Array();

    if($("#appr:checked").length > 0)
    {
        $('#send').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#slct_appr').attr('disabled',true);
    }

    if($("#appr:checked").length == 0)
    {
        $('#send').attr('disabled',false);
        $('#slct_appr').attr('disabled',false);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: still cannot...i try put disabled on dropdown and not disabled send button but still the same...look here http://jsfiddle.net/frantic912/3YbZu/2/